# Using Akeneo PIM as a stocklist database for stocks of different suppliers

Tags: database, akeneo

does it make sense to use Akeneo as a database for the data provided from our suppliers?
we are talking about 100 - 200 suppliers with 3 - 4 millions of products.
we don't have a database and we lack the know-how to build one.

the idea is to customize tables and columns and use the import/export function..

thanks & cheers

Comment: Why not simply use the dedicated Akeneo product?
akeneo.com/akeneo-onboarder/